# Как настроить редирект на созданный поддомен (сервер nginx)?

Tags: nginx

Недавно приобрел VDS и сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с добавлением поддоменов. К VDS привязан домен, например example.com. Под него создан ssl сертификат (с помощью certbot) и соответственно настроен (+прописал в /etc/hosts -> 127.0.0.1 example.com) конфиг nginx:

```
server {
  listen            80;
  listen            [::]:80;

  server_name           example.com www.example.com;
  return 301            https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen            443 ssl http2;
  listen            [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name           www.example.com;
  return 301            https://example.com$request_uri;

  ssl_certificate       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

  include           snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}

server {
  listen            443 ssl http2;
  listen            [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name           example.com;
  root              /var/www/example.com/public;
  index             index.php index.html index.xml;

  ssl_certificate       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

  include           snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  # Connect php fpm
  include           snippets/fastcgi-standart.conf;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/example__com__access.log;
  error_log         /var/log/nginx/example__com__error.log;
}
```

Для переадресации с www->на без www и с http на https. Сейчас хочу настроить phpmyadmin, столкнулся с проблемой, по инструкции на сайте хостера говорилось, что достаточно только поставить `apt install phpmyadmin` и он будет доступен по адрес `IP_SITE/phpmyadmin`.

Но у меня этот вариант не завелся, предположил, что виной всему конфиг nginx(правда где "собака зарыта" ХЗ). Попытался реализовать такой вариант - создать поддомен pma.example.com. После чего проделал манипуляцию, как и с основным доменом:

- Прописал в `/etc/hosts -> 127.0.0.1 pma.example.com`
- Сделал конфиг nginx (без переадресации на https):

```
server {
  listen            80;
  listen            [::]:80;

  server_name           pma.example.com www.pma.example.com;
  root              /var/www/phpmyadmin; (это символическая ссылка, реально находиться по стандартному пути /usr/share/phpmyadmin)
  index             index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  # Connect php fpm
  include           snippets/fastcgi-standart.conf;
  
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_access.log;
  error_log         /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_error.log;
}
```

Но при попытке перейти по `https://pma.example.com/` меня редиректит на `https://example.com/`. И я ума не приложу, как исправить. VDS пользуюсь впервые, поэтому возможно не вижу каких-то очевидных вещей. Чего я хочу добиться:

- Что бы phpmyadmin был доступен по адресу pma.example.com
  или
- Что бы phpmyadmin был доступен по `example.com/phpmyadmin` (вариант более приоритетен, так как не надо будет заморачиваться с ssl, так как у certbot я ненашел опции выдавать ssl на домен + поддомены)

Comment: `меня редиректит` добавляете/изменяете конфиг перегружайте `nginx -s reload`! И тестируйте в режиме инкогнито или например через `curl`. 301 перенаправление очень опасное и в кэше может засесть на долго! `не нашел опции выдавать ssl на домен + поддомены` плохо ищите.

Comment: >> не нашел опции выдавать ssl на домен + поддомены
я сейчас говорю про snap пакет, а не платное предоставление хостингом сертификаты. Вы ттоже это имели ввиду? 

Насчет nginx попробую, но заходит и в инкогнито и в режиме гостя и с другого браузера.